# My laptop freeze or has black screen when I open the lid after suspend

Tags: power-management, suspend, laptop, dmesg, systemd-journald

Since when I bought this laptop (Huawei Matebook D14, it has a AMD Ryzen 5 3500U CPU with a Radeon Vega 8 GPU) and installed Linux on it (it's dualbooting with Windows), I have this problem that happens randomly, not always, but it's very annoying.

Basically when I open the lid of my laptop, it freezes. I can't do anything. The only thing I can do is to shutdown manually with the button.

Actually in this last period, it doesn't freeze, but the screen is black. I only can see the cursor and it changes when I move it in different areas of the screen (in fact even if I can't see anything, if I try to put the password and press enter, I notice that in someway I am able to login because my cursor change again and it's like I am moving the cursor in the windows that I had when I closed the lid, but again, I can't see anything). Since I don't see anything, I can only manually shutdown with the button (I tried going to a tty but I can't see anything too). It's a very annoying bug because I lose every activity of the session.

I have this problem in all the distros that I have tried: Manjaro, Kubuntu, etc.. and now also in Archlinux with KDE.

The problem happens sometimes. Not always. I noticed that sometimes (with the lid closed) the fan are working and when I open the lid I have the bug described. Maybe it's related to the fan(?)
The fan powering on when lid is closed are also on Windows, but Windows doesn't freeze.

I am able to login via SSH when all this happens.

This is journalctl log where I was able to move the cursor and also enter the password and login (even if I didn't see anything):
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=296561

journalctl when I closed lid at 19:37:51. I opened the lid at 19:55:06 and it was black as usual and I couldn't see anything, I can just move the cursor and also I can put the password and login (I can because if I do it I notice that the cursor changes like if I am moving around the windows that I had opened before I closed the lid, but again, I can't see anything). As you can see, the laptop does not suspend. Is it maybe interrupted by NetworkManager(?). I am able to login via SSH.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=296563

this time I didn't close the lid, I just left the laptop without power cable, so I think it went in suspension after some minutes (10:11:54 precisely in the logs). After some time I went again to the laptop(10:27:53) and realized that it was suspended, but I saw that it freezed again.... Classic black screen.
I could access via SSH, so I decided to poweroff via SSH(10:29:49), instead of manually and forcibly powering off via button. But I waited and nothing was happening, laptop wasn't shut dowm, it's like it was freezed in shutdown process.
here's the related journalctl:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=296565

If I close the lid and I go to sleep, and the morning I run "dmesg -T", I notice that my pc has activities even if it should be suspended for all the night. Is it normal or it isn't?